# numbers that cannot be expressed in closed form?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

> Irrational numbers can be divided into two categories:
>   - **Algebraic**
>   - **Transcendental**

But there are some numbers that are roots of polynomial ie. are algebraic but cannot be expressed in closed form expression.
Eg. $\sin10^o,\sin20^o etc.$
$\sin10^o$  is a root of $8x^3-6x+1=0$ but it is not possible to express it in [closed form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091913/closed-form-expression-for-sin-10o)

What are such numbers called?

Comment: It is not as simple and well known as the formula for quadratic polynomials but there is a formula for cubic polynomials: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html.  There is also one for quartics.  When you get to quintics, a solution in radicals (using roots) might not be possible.

Comment: @badjohn for this particular case it is not possible, you can check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091913/closed-form-expression-for-sin-10o here

Comment: Be careful with the phrase "can't be written in closed form". What can and can't be written in closed form is decided by the (somewhat arbitrary) conventional set of operations we mathematicians "allow". For instance, for an elementary schooler, $x^2-2=0$ doesn't have a closed form solution. Then they learn about the square root symbol, but that doesn't help them with $x^3-2=0$. Some years later they learn the general root symbol, which lets them write a lot of other numbers in closed form. But still, to them, $x^2+1=0$ doesn't have a closed form solution until they reach complex numbers.

Comment: (cont.) My point is that the fact that we stop there, and haven't invented a new piece of notation next to roots and complex numbers that allows us to go even further, is completely arbitrary. If you are specific about which notation you want, then that's fine, but just "closed form" is a bit too ambiguous.

Comment: @Arthur my definition of closed form is tht it can be expressed as surds, it is not a complex number as a value for $\sin 10^o$ does exist, it just uses elementary binary operations etc.and in this definition it is not possible to express it

Comment: I think the use of the term "algebraic number of high degree" or so is relevant here?

Comment: As Arthur says, "closed form" does not have a fixed precise definition.  So, you would say that $x^2 + 1 = 0$ does not have a solution in closed form?  Fair enough but some others would say that it did.  A possible expression, rather than name for what you want, is "expressible by radicals".

Comment: (...cntd...) or was it "numbers of algebraic height of <something>" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the theorem you want is that an algebraic number can be written as a root tower if and only if the Galois group of its minimal polynomial over the rationals is solvable (as a group).  That is how Galois proved that there is no general solution for the quintic polynomial.  $S_5$ is not solvable so just find a quintic polynomial with Galois group $S_5$.

I am not aware of any name for such algebraic numbers.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by unsolvable.  If you mean irreducible, then if any root is expressible as a root tower, the Galois group of the polynomial is solvable so they all will be.  The Galois group of any quintic polynomial is a subgroup of $S_5$ and the only subgroups of $S_5$ that aren’t solvable are $S_5$ itself and $A_5$.